# When using custom pipe transform function, removing data from property bindings does not reflect in the template view in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an array of items, that before I display I use a custom pipe transform function to modify the displayed data to the user like this:

```
`
<mat-chip               
              [removable]="true"
              (removed)="onRemoveImage(storeImage)"                                  
              *ngFor="let storeImage of storeImages | storeImageView">{{ storeImage.name }}  
              <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
`
```

The storeImageView pipe transform function, simple takes the array, iterates through all of its objects, creates copies of the objects and on those copies, transforms the name property to display in the UI.

the pipe function:
`

```
transform(storeImages: StoreImage[]): StoreImage[] {   
    let viewImagesArr: StoreImage[] = [];    

    for (let index = 0; index < storeImages.length; index++) {
      let viewImage = Object.assign({}, storeImages[index]);
      viewImage.name = viewImage.name = viewImage.name.slice(0, 4) + viewImage.ID.slice(0, 4);
      viewImagesArr = [...viewImagesArr, viewImage];
    }
    return viewImagesArr;
  }
```

`

If user has two items added to the array, they all display just fine in the DOM. As soon as user goes to delete an item, the remove function gets triggered and deletes the item from the array, but the DOM does not update. When I take out the pipe operator in the HTML template and I do NOT transform the output, it all works as expected. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your pipe is a `pure` pipe, either make it impure. Or when you delete an item from the array, change the reference of the array.

1. Make the pipe impure:  `@Pipe({ name: 'pipeName', pure: false})`

---

2. Or after you do a delete, do something like: `this.storeImages  = [...this.storeImages ]`, I feel doing this is a better performant approach.

Comment: so make my delete function pure, by creating a new reference with filtered array?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh Your delete function would anyway be pure (I assume so), just create a new reference of the `storageImages` array after you delete.

Comment: perfect thank you! That solved it. I did this.storeImages = this.storeImages.filter(i => i.ID !== image.ID) and it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are pure functions.
The change detection of the pipe only runs when there is a reference change as it follows the idealogy of immutability.
You are working with an array which is basically object and change detection for object is when the object reference changes

So if you require the change to be reflected when you delete change the reference of the array.

```
oldArray = [...]; // this is the array that has data

onDelete(itemToBeDeteled/index){
// if index is there then
oldArray = [].concat[oldArray.splice(index,1)];// ***shallow cloning of arrays***
// if item is present
// Your logic based on the item and create a new array after that and assign it to the array that is referenced in HTML.
}
```

If the item is an array inside the oldArray then we need to perform deep cloning.

this is a clean way to work with angular pipes.As change detection is not run again and again.Other way is to use impure pipes which brings down the performance.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes